# Uncaught TypeError: method is not a function

Tags: javascript, typeerror

Code:

```
function Hotel(name,rooms,bookings){

    this.name = name;
    this.rooms = rooms;
    this.bookings = bookings;

    this.checkAvailability = function(){
        return this.rooms - this.bookings;
    }

    this.bookRoom = function(){
        if(this.checkAvailability() > 1){
            return this.bookings++;
        }
    }

    this.cancelBooking = function(){
        if(this.bookings < 1){
            return this.bookings--;
        }
    }
}


var grandHotel = new Hotel('Hotel Grand', 20, 5);
var addBooking = document.getElementById("book");

addBooking.addEventListener('click', grandHotel.bookRoom, false);
```

If I click the addBooking element I get this error:

> Uncaught TypeError: this.checkAvailability is not a function.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How does the "this" keyword work?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127429/how-does-the-this-keyword-work)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to change how the event is being bound.

```
addBooking.addEventListener('click', grandHotel.bookRoom.bind(grandHotel), false);
```

or

```
addBooking.addEventListener('click', function() { grandHotel.bookRoom(); }, false);
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this.

Now i get it, thought I can directly place a method in the function parameter of the addEventlistener .

Truly appreciate your help sir.

Comment: @nikodeguzman note that the problem is way more commonly solved by capturing "this" in closure (like `var that=this;` and using `that` instead of this).

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov Um, Where is the `this` here? I know what you are saying, but in this case there is no this,  The "this" is `grandHotel`

Comment: @epascarello on the line that failed? If OP would use `that.checkAvailability()` inside `bookRoom` it would work perfectly fine with original code to add event listener.